# Difference between Endorsing Peer and Committing peer in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am quit confused with these two peers since I am new to Fabric. If any body help me with this.

Answer (score 8):

Endorsing peers are basically approvers.

[image: Difference]
[image: Transaction Flow]

Answer (score 2):

A transaction has to be proposed and then endorsed before it can be submitted successfully to the blockchain.

**Endorsing peer** is the peer that will "endorse"/provide the seal of approval to a transaction when it is proposed. After the transaction is endorsed, the transaction(plus the endorsement) will be submitted to blockchain.

Once the Transaction is submitted, it will make way to the peers that are supposed to get that transaction. These peers will then "commit"/save the transaction in their Ledger, and these are the **committer** peers.

The committing peers and endorsing peers can be the same peers sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the difference among those Peers, I thinks that it is important to know where takes part its Peer in the [flow of a transaction](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/txflow.html) of Hyperledger Fabric.

- A proposal is send to the Endorser Peers. These Peers verify the proposal, execute it and send the reply signed to the client.
- The client inspect those replies. If they result is succesfull, it generates a new transaction with the replies of the Endorser Peers and sends it to the Ordering Service.
- The Ordering Service executes its operations and sends the block to the corresponding Peers, i.e. the Commiters.
- The Commiters append each block to the corresponding ledger.

As @adnan.c said:

> "The committing peers and endorsing peers can be the same peers
>   sometimes."