# Hyperledger Fabric - Difference between Endorsement and Validation

Tags: validation, hyperledger-fabric

I am confused between endorsement and validation steps of Fabric. A little clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Endorsing Peer and Committing peer in Hyperledger Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893818/difference-between-endorsing-peer-and-committing-peer-in-hyperledger-fabric)

Answer (score 0):

Endorsement the the process where the endorsing peers execute the transaction and agree upon the same result whereas validation is the process of checking the endorsements and read write sets  and avoid invalid and conflicting transactions